# How do you post form submissions to a Google Drive Spreadsheet using Google App Scripts

Tags: post, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-drive-api

I want to create a form on my site that when a user submits, it posts their data to a particular Spreadsheet in my Google Drive. How can I do this with Google App Scripts?

sample form

```
<form method='post' action='https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxxx.....'>
  Favorite Color <input type='text' value='' name='color' />
  Favorite Ice Cream Flavor <input type='text' value='' name='flavor' />
  <input type='button' value='submit' />
</form>
```

so that when I hit submit it creates a record in a Google Drive Spreadsheet

```
| color | flavor |
   red    vanilla
```

Is this doable with GAS, or is sort of task more suited for the Google Drive SDK (via Javascript)?

---

**UPDATE**

Used the example from [How to add form elements to UI App Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp#Forms) to complete the script

**This is the current script I've thrown together... and it works!!!**

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = '0Aqa6DbU_0sv7dGNrMEEybjNrdm00MlpwTTNx...';

function doPost(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName('RequestInvites').appendRow([e.parameter.emailAddress, 'hash123']);

  app.add(app.createLabel("Form submitted. Your email address is: '" + e.parameter.emailAddress));

  return app;
}

function createForm(e){
   var app  = UiApp.createApplication();
   var form = app.createFormPanel();
   var flow = app.createFlowPanel();

   flow.add(app.createLabel('Enter your email address to get an invitation').setId('inviteLabel'));
   flow.add(app.createTextBox().setId('emailAddress').setName('emailAddress'));
   flow.add(app.createSubmitButton("Request Invite"));
   form.add(flow);

   app.add(form);
   return app;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with GAS. In your script, use `function doPost(e)` to retrieve user inputs when the submit button (that you might have forgotten ;) is cliked.

In the doPost function, you can access inputs with their 'name' attribute like that : `e.parameter.color` and `e.parameter.flavor`.

Then, you can use Spreadsheet service to write in your spreadsheet. Documentation for this service is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_spreadsheet). So you open your spreadsheet, and add a row in the correct sheet like that : `SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of your spreadsheet').getSheetByName('colors_and_flavors').appendRow([e.parameter.color, e.parameter.flavor]);`.

Let's recap :

```
function doPost(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('id of your spreadsheet').getSheetByName('colors_and_flavors').appendRow([e.parameter.color, e.parameter.flavor]);
}
```

Hope it helps ! ;)

Comment: Thanks for the doPost explanation. The issue now is that I'm using the UI service to generate an app. Right now I have a very basic script. Maybe you can help me figure whats wrong. ill update my question  -- second thought I just realized I needed to add a Form element.