# Google Apps Script - Submit PDF Form Data (Image)

Tags: forms, pdf, google-apps-script, adobe, acrobat

Is there a Google Apps Script that can retrieve form data from a fillable pdf form and export it to my Google Drive when I click submit form? I don't need the complete document to be exported, it's only a selected field (image-field) that I particularly need to be exported. I am working from Adobe Acrobat Pro. I'm sorry I have no code to show what I have tried so far because I am a novice in this.

Updated:
According to Adobe, submitForm () function is one of the most flexible ways of moving data in and out of a form as it uses GET to send or receive data from a web server. Where the submitForm () has a variety of input arguments for just about any data format from the entire pdf to images.

One forum (on [Adobe Library](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/Submit-gDrive-q152400.aspx)), raised an exact question, and a brief response provided to look into Google Apps Script. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976777/how-do-you-post-form-submissions-to-a-google-drive-spreadsheet-using-google-app) on stack overflow - the user wanted a form submission from their Site to GDrive Spreadsheet using GAS. Whereas I have a standalone PDF form, and on form submission, I need the (image) data from the pdf form exported to my GDrive Folder.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `a selected field (image-field)`. And I cannot understand about the situation about the action when you click the submit button. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: _I'm sorry I have no code to show what I have tried so far because I am a novice in this._ I do understand, but would you please tell us what research you did before you posted your question.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for responding. In Adobe Acrobat Pro, there are a few options to export the data from the pdf form, including submitting data to a server, via email, etc. On submit form, I want the form data exported to my Google Drive Folder. The fillable form includes an image field - to mean respondents will also attach an image when completing the form. And I wish to have the image data exported to my GDrive, if possible through GAS. I have updated my question with links, to give more detail.

Comment: @Tedinoz I appreciate the response. I have updated the question relating to my research done so far, with a link to a similar question, if it helps, it's not much.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to confirm about my understanding of your goal. In your goal, you want to retrieve all images from a PDF file and want to create them to Google Drive as the image files. And, you want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? I have one more question. Can I ask you about `the (image) data from the pdf form`? I think that I cannot still correctly understand about it. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike. Yes, you understood 100%. "Image data from PDF" - I was trying to emphasize my goal of retrieving the images. Sorry, if that was confusing.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your goal. In this case, how about the following flow? 1. Convert the PDF file to PPTX using [the external API](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-pptx). 2. Retrieve all images from Google Document using Document service. 3. Create the retrieved images as the files using Drive service. By this flow, I think that your goal can be achieved. Unfortunately, when Google APIs are used, the images are not included in the converted file. So I proposed to use the external API. But if you don't want to use the external API, I apologize for this.

Comment: I will implement this external API solution that you have given, considering there is no other option. Thanks so much for providing this  - it will help with my workflow.  @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will help users who have the same issue.